# How do I serve Webpack bundles with EJS templates?

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, ejs

I'm trying to put together a basic fullstack application using Express and EJS, with Webpack bundling my static assets. One of the dilemmas I've come across is: my different routes in Express return server-side-built HTML using EJS, but I can't work out how to connect those templates to the webpack assets that I'm building.

I'd really appreciate advice on the following issues:

1) Deployment structure. 
Currently I have a file structure that looks like this:

root

--- app.js (my express appliation)

--- models

--- views

--- routes

--- public (the static assets)

------ src (entry point for webpack is index.js in here)

------ dist (output for webpack goes here)

--- webpack.config.js

What makes intuitive sense to me is that webpack would build a dist folder that sits at the root level, or that would be put in nginx or somewhere for serving static files. But if I'm deploying with a PaaS like Heroku would that be the 'right thing to do'? I'm guessing it doesn't matter so long as my html is using the correct paths.

2) How do I link up Webpack to EJS? I've looked into the following two loaders:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs-loader and https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs-html-loader as well as others, but for some reason they seem to require that you pass in your inline variables in the config file, rather than in your Express routes, which doesn't make much sense to me.
What I'm looking to do is have some sort of workflow where when Express renders the routes the EJS templates and HTML correctly source the bundled JS and CSS.

It's worth saying I'm *not* trying to do bundled server-side JS. I'm trying to bundle the frontend assets, and get Express to serve up EJS-built HTML that uses those bundled files.

It would be really great to have any help with this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? Cause I have very similar problem.