# Bundler similar to webpack that can compile node.js express and EJS files

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, ejs

After trying to set up **webpack5 + express + ejs** to no avail, I'm looking for some kind of "bundler" that will optimize my server code (files) so those will be automatically minified/uglified/obfuscated/bundled/converted to ES5/ etc. when there is any code change. It must support server side EJS partials (cause I have almost finished project that use EJS from scratch), has option to modify (for example bundle/not bundle) or leave intact specific files.

I know what bundlers there are on the market but I did not try them - I don't know which one is best suited for my needs (if any, besides webpack ofcourse - cause I'm to stupid to properly set it up, cause of [How do I serve Webpack bundles with EJS templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59079079/how-do-i-serve-webpack-bundles-with-ejs-templates) or
[Webpack 5 + express + EJS templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68246882/webpack-5-express-ejs-templates) ...).

*Ejs render loaders seems to require that you pass in your inline variables in the config file, rather than in your Express routes, which doesn't make much sense to me.*

webpack: 5.38.1
express": 4.17.1
ejs-render-loader: 1.0.0*

I have difficulties configuring Webpack 5 to properly use EJS template files. Setup looks like this:

INDEX.JS

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var page1 = require('./routes/page1.js');
var page2 = require('./routes/page2.js');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/ejs');
var server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(port, host, function()
{
    console.log('server is running!');
}
app.use('/page1', page1);
app.use('/page2', page2);
// + bla bla bla
```

PAGE1.JS

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next)
{
    res.render('page1', {data : data}); // here we render ejs file
    res.end();
}
router.post('/page2', function(req, res, next)
{
    // + bla bla bla
    res.render('page2', {data : data}); // here we render ejs file
    res.end();
}
```

PAGE1.EJS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PAGE1</title>
    <%- include ('head.ejs'); %>
</head>
<body>
    <%- include ('header.ejs'); %>
    <%- include ('menu.ejs'); %>
    <div class="errors">
        <% if (typeof errors == "undefined") { %>
        <% } else { %>
            <%- errors %>
        <% } %>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

PAGE2.JS

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next)
{
    res.render('page1', {data : data}); // here we render ejs file
    res.end();
}
```

PAGE2.EJS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PAGE2</title>
    <%- include ('head.ejs'); %>
</head>
<body>
    <%- include ('container.ejs'); %>
</body>
</html>
```

WEBPACK.CONFIG.JS

```
module.exports = {
    target: "node",
    entry: {
        main: './SRC/index.js'
    },
    externalsPresets: {node: true},
    externals: [webpackNodeExternals()],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ejs$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'ejs-render-loader'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Can somebody who has working config, show his settings, so I can adjust mine? Cause now EJS files are not bundled - seems webpack has problem with included data inside those files. Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: EDITED to better describe my problem.